# Ruby native extension gems install fails

Tags: ruby

When trying to install a ruby gem that uses native extensions my installs are failing.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

The log file gives me the following output

```
"gcc-mp-4.9 -o conftest -I/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.4.0 -I/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/opt/local/include  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L.  -L/opt/local/lib      -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

It appears this is looking for a macports version of gcc instead of using the system gcc, but I don't even have any macports gcc installs on the system.

------ EDIT adding output from gem_make.out file ---------

```
/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160428-64282-8h2kw8.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lcups... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
    --with-cupslib
    --without-cupslib
/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you using RBENV or RVM?

Comment: There should be a more detailed stack trace along with the build error. But looking at what it's trying to compile I'd say either your compiler is broken or you're missing ruby headers.

Comment: I've added the output from the gem_make.out file now as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that the gcc setting is sticky in the rbconfig.rb file for the rvm gemset.

I had to go to

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.4.0/rbconfig.rb
```

There I had to change

```
CONFIG["CC"] = "gcc-mp-4.9"
```

to

```
CONFIG["CC"] = "gcc"
```

and also change

```
CONFIG["configure_args"] = " '--prefix=/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551' '--with-opt-dir=/opt/local' '--without-tcl' '--without-tk' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared' 'CC=gcc-mp-4.9'"
```

to

```
CONFIG["configure_args"] = " '--prefix=/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551' '--with-opt-dir=/opt/local' '--without-tcl' '--without-tk' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared' 'CC=gcc'"
```